# PHP Session not setting

Tags: php, session

I have a PHP page and session, i **started session** on top of every site, but this isn't working. 
I'm setting session (I'm setting class into session) with

```
}else if(isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
  $account = new Account;
  $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password']);
  $account->setTheAccount($_POST['username'],$password);
  $acc_data = $account->getDatabaseAccounts('root','','schoolpage','localhost','accounts');
  $acc_status = $account->isAccountTrue();
  if ($acc_status==true){
    $_SESSION['account'] = $account;
    echo 'true';
    header('Location:panel.php');
  }else{
    echo 'false';
  }
}
```

and accessing it by:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['account'])){
      $account = $_SESSION['account'];
        if ($account->isAccountTrue() == true){
          echo 'XD';
        }
      }
```

but it doesnt work.
I haven't idea why session not working.

#### Account class

```
class Account{
  private $acc_data,$username,$password;
  function setTheAccount($usernamei, $passwordi){
    $this->username = $usernamei;
    $this->password = $passwordi;
  }
  function getDatabaseAccounts($dbUser,$dbPassword,$dbName,$dbHost, $dbTable){
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbHost.';dbname='.$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPassword);
    $this->acc_data = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM `'.$dbTable.'`');
  }
  function isAccountTrue(){
    $acc_status=false;
    foreach ($this->acc_data as $i) {
      if ($i['username'] == $this->username and $i['password'] == $this->password){
        $acc_status = true;
      }
    }
    return $acc_status;
  }
  function isUserLogged(){

  }
}
```

Account class var dump

```
truearray(2) { ["login"]=> bool(true) ["account"]=> object(Account)#1 (3) { ["acc_data":"Account":private]=> object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(24) "SELECT * FROM `accounts`" } ["username":"Account":private]=> string(5) "admin" ["password":"Account":private]=> string(64) "4813494d137e1631bba301d5acab6e7bb7aa74ce1185d456565ef51d737677b2" } }
```

Comment: have you start the session with [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)?

Comment: Where is `$_SESSION['account']` being set?

Comment: @chriz at login page, i will give you more code.

Comment: Is the base URL on each page the same? `www.example.com` and `example.com` don't share sessions.

Comment: @OrangeFlash81 yes, i use localhost

Comment: is it value or creating object `$_SESSION['account']` ?

Comment: looking for this `$_SESSION['account']->isAccountTrue()` ?

Comment: My guess is that the `$_SESSION['account']` is not being set. Run `var_dump($_SESSION)` and see what is inside.

Comment: can we look the `Account` class?

Comment: @devpro its object

Comment: So what was inside the `var_dump($_SESSION)`? Did you see `account` in the results?

Comment: @chriz yes, full content in post.

Comment: And where are you calling `session_start`?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem on top of the page.

Comment: @qcperek: Define "top of the page" is where I'm getting at. Show us where/how `session_start` is being called. If headers have been sent prior to you starting the session, it won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store an object in $_SESSION you have to serialize it, then deserialize it to call the method ->isAccountTrue(), otherwise just store the result:

```
$_SESSION['accountValid']=$account->isAccountTrue();
...
if($_SESSION['accountValid']===true){
// do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

on top of the page to enable the php errors, and you will see that you can't serialize a resource, PDO instances, PDOStatement, etc. into session.

You can't serialize Account's `$acc_data`, since it's an instance of PDOStatement. You cannot serialize or unserialize PDOStatement instances.

Change

```
$this->acc_data = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM `'.$dbTable.'`');
```

to

```
$this->acc_data = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM `'.$dbTable.'`')->fetchAll();
```

then delete your session and retry.